# SAS: sum across columns and set to missing if any missing

Tags: sas

Is there a nice way to sum across columns, but set the answer to missing if any are missing? Effectively the following:

```
    if cmiss(of eTimeOffWork -- eNotAbleToDoJob) = 0
        then work = sum(of eTimeOffWork -- eNotAbleToDoJob);
```

Is there function like `sum` that does this out of the box?

Comment: I'm not sure about SAS but what happens if you drop the SUM and just do the math in the parenthesis?

Comment: If cmiss( ... ) gt 0 then work=.;

Comment: Note there is no need to use CMISS() with variables you want to sum.  You can use NMISS() since by definition all of the variables involved must be numeric.

Comment: I don't understand why a single function would be any better than the IF statement you are already using.  Why make the code more confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Standard addition will do this, but you will have to specify every variable:

`foo = var1 + var2 + var3 + ... + varn`

The way you're doing it is the easiest way.

You could turn it into your own function if you wanted to and make it a bit cleaner in the data step code. It gets tricky with fcmp because you must provide the variables to sum in an array. I wouldn't recommend doing this but this is an option available to you.

An example that does this is provided for you in the SAS documentation:
https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0f3ukbprxtdfrn1cljibie17wzn.htm

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.funcs;
    function summiss(n[*]) varargs;
        sum = 0;

        do i = 1 to dim(n);
            sum = sum + n[i];
        end;

        return(sum);
    endfunc;
run;

options cmplib=work.funcs;

data test;
    array vars[5] (1, 2, 3, 4, .);

    foo = summiss(vars);
run;
```